# verilog array referencing

Tags: verilog

I have this module. The question is `gameArray[0][x][y-1]` doesn't work. What is the correct way to perform this kind of operation? Basically it is similar to C++ syntax but can not get it to work.

```
module write_init_copy(
  input clk,
  input gameArray [1:0][63:0][127:0], writecell, processedcell,
  input [5:0] x,
  input [6:0] y,
  input initialize, copyover,
  output reg done_initialize, done_copy, done_writecell);

always@(posedge clk)
begin
    if(writecell == 1)
    begin
        gameArray[1][x][y] <= processedcell;
        done_writecell <= 1;
    end
    else if(initialize == 1)
    begin

    end
end

endmodule
```

Comment: How did you declare `gameArray`?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the ports of the module?  The 4'the port... Or is it just a simple cut and wast error?

Comment: @vermaete @ timrau edited. refresh tnx

Comment: What error are you seeing? gameArray[] is an array of wires so procedural assignments won't work. The left hand side must be a variable(like reg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gameArray is declared as an input so you can't assign to it.  If you want you want to modify it declare a separate 'in' and 'out' version where out <= f(in);  i.e.

```
gameArray_out <= gameArray_in;
gameArray_out[1][x][y] <= procesedcell;
```